# Architecture / method to pass data between member variable (a class instance) of an express server

Tags: javascript, typescript, express

I am writing a class for express, to use as a monitoring server for a library. I need to create the different routers and routes, but I need to access functions and variables from the monitor-server class. I have just passed the this variable to the different routes. Is there a better solution / architecture I should be using to construct the different routers and initialize them? The express server needs to be represented as a class.

### monitor-server.ts

```
import * as express from 'express'
import * as path from 'path';
import * as cookieParser from 'cookie-parser';
import * as logger from 'morgan';
import * as cors from 'cors';
import * as useragent from 'express-useragent';
import * as http from 'http';
import * as process from 'process';
import {EventEmitter} from "events";
const authRouter = require('./routes/auth');
export class MonitorServer extends EventEmitter {
    public app: express.Application;
    private server: http.Server ;
    private port = 3000;
    private type: 0 | 1 = 1;
    private dBMode: 0 | 1 | 2 = 0;
    private admin ?: {
        username: string;
        password: string;
    };
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.app = express();
        this.app.set('port', this.port);
        this.app.set('type', this.type);
        this.initializeMiddlewares();
        this.initializeControllers();
        this.listen();
    }
    private initializeMiddlewares() {
        // initialize middlewares
    }
    private initializeControllers() {
        this.app.use('/auth', authRouter.router);
        authRouter.setMonitorServer(this);
    }
    public listen() {
        this.server = http.createServer(this.app);
        this.server.listen(this.port);
    }
}
```

### auth.ts

```
import * as express from "express";
import {MonitorServer} from "../monitor-server";
let router = express.Router();
let monitor: MonitorServer;
function setMonitorServer(monitorServer: MonitorServer) {
    monitor = monitorServer;
}
router.get('/admin', (req, res) => {
    // access variables and data within monitor-server class
});
router.get('/operationMode', (req, res) => {
    // access variables and data within monitor-server class
});
module.exports = {router, setMonitorServer};
```

Answer (score 1):

If the methods and variables from MonitorServer are public, you should be able to just call them using the 'monitor' variable.

For example:

## monitor-server.ts

```
export class MonitorServer extends EventEmitter {
   
   public somePublicFunction() {
      doSomeStuff();
   }
}
```

## auth.ts

```
let monitor: MonitorServer;
function setMonitorServer(monitorServer: MonitorServer) {
    monitor = monitorServer;
}
router.get('/admin', (req, res) => {
    if (monitor) {
        monitor.somePublicFunction();
    }
})};
```

Does that answer your question? Or were you wondering how to do it without the setMonitorServer() call in auth.ts?

Comment: I am currently using as you have shown in your example, but is passing the this keyword the correct way to go about this or is there another way? Without passing this to authRouter. Maybe use authRouter in another way than just exporting it?

Comment: If you really want to decouple them, instead of having the _definition_ of your class  require the authRouter, you could instead expose the _instantiation_ of a MonitorServer and have the authRouter use that.

Without more context, I'm not sure how you are using these, but I'm assuming that there is only ever 1 instance of a MonitorServer and 1 instance of an AuthRouter.

So you could do 
*someOtherFile.ts*
`const monitorServer = new MonitorServer();
export monitorServer;`
*auth.ts*
`import monitorServer from 'somewhere';
if (monitorServer) {
monitorServer.somePublicFunction()
}`